# C++ Overloaded Constructor issues

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm trying to create an overloaded constructor inside my player.cpp but it's giving me the error that there is no instance of overloaded function "player:player" matches the specified type.

Here is the header for reference

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Item.h"

using namespace std;

class player{
public:

//Data members
string name;
int lvl;
int exp;    
double maxweight;
double currentweight;
int health;
int strenght;
int defence;
DLinkedList<Item> inventory;

//Constructor
player();
player(string name, int level, int experience, double maxweight, double currentweight, int health, int strenght, int defence, DLinkedList<Item> inventory);
~player();  
};

#endif
```

and here is the .cpp

```
#include "player.h"
#include "Item.h"
#include "DLinkedList.h"

// ----------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:           Constructor
//  Description:    Constructor
//  Arguments:      
//  Return Value:   None.
// ----------------------------------------------------------------

player::player(){
    this ->name = "default";
    this ->lvl = 99;
    this ->exp = 99;
    this ->maxweight = 99;
    this ->currentweight = 99;
    this ->health = 99;
    this ->strenght = 99;
    this ->defence = 99;
    this ->inventory;
}

player::player(string name, int level, int experience, double maxweight, double currentweight, int health, int strenght, int defence, DLinkedList<Item> inventory){
    this ->name = name;
    this ->lvl = lvl;
    this ->exp = exp;
    this ->maxweight = maxweight;
    this ->currentweight = currentweight;
    this ->health = health;
    this ->strenght = strenght;
    this ->defence = defence;   
    this ->inventory = inventory;
}
```

Here is the main where I create the player object

```
DLinkedList<player> list;   
DLinkedList<Item> inventory;

//creates and appends a few default players to the linked list
player player1 = player("Jeremy", 2, 4 ,95, 5, 4, 3, 2, inventory);


list.Append(player1);
```

I am pretty sure that is wrong however since I want each inventory to be unique to each player.

Here is some of the output errors related to the issue

```
c:\users\liam\desktop\ca2 liam\doublelinkedlistca2\doublelinkedlistca2\player.h(22): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>c:\users\liam\desktop\ca2 liam\doublelinkedlistca2\doublelinkedlistca2\player.h(22): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\liam\desktop\ca2 liam\doublelinkedlistca2\doublelinkedlistca2\player.h(22): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
1>c:\users\liam\desktop\ca2 liam\doublelinkedlistca2\doublelinkedlistca2\player.h(26): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'DLinkedList'
1>c:\users\liam\desktop\ca2 liam\doublelinkedlistca2\doublelinkedlistca2\player.cpp(21): error C2039: 'inventory' : is not a member of 'player'
1>          c:\users\liam\desktop\ca2 liam\doublelinkedlistca2\doublelinkedlistca2\player.h(10) : see declaration of 'player'
1>c:\users\liam\desktop\ca2 liam\doublelinkedlistca2\doublelinkedlistca2\player.cpp(24): error C2511: 'player::player(std::string,int,int,double,double,int,int,int,DLinkedList<Datatype>)' : overloaded member function not found in 'player'
```

Comment: Could you post the code that is creating the player object?

Comment: You should post the entire actual error message instead of paraphrasing it.

Comment: This is what they call "vexing parse"...

Comment: Without seeing the full error message, it's a bit difficult to help here, but I wonder if the lack of a copy constructor in the player class is causing the problem, when you try to append it to the DLinkedList. Can you please post the full error that you're getting?

Comment: It's usually best to look at the first error first. Later errors (such as the one about the constructor) are often caused by earlier ones (in this case, failure to generate the constructor due to failing to generate one of the members due to not knowing about its type), and often go away once the earlier ones are fixed.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to:

```
#include "DLinkedList.h"
```

in player.h. That causes an error in line 22:

```
DLinkedList<Item> inventory;
```

because `DLinkedList` is unknown to the compiler.

Comment: Thanks man I think that worked. I am still worried that the way I am creating the player object will not allow a unique inventory for each player.